# Set port to event field logstash

Tags: logging, logstash, syslog, logstash-configuration

For reasons that are irrelevant to my question, I need to set my port to an event field. I have not been able to yet. This is sample code to show the issue.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "the_port" => 12345 }
    convert   => { "the_port" => "integer" } # not needed, just in case
  }
}

output {
  syslog {
    facility => "local0"
    severity => "warning"
    host = [the_host]
    port = [the_port] # this throws the error
  }
}
```

Logstash throws an error here (running /bin/logstash -f syslog.conf --configtest) saying:

```
Invalid setting for syslog output plugin:
  # This setting must be a number
  # Expected number, got "the_port" (type the_port)
  port => ["the_port"]
```

After looking at logstash source code it looks like logstash is doing some checking on port value before fully expanding it from the variable. This can be confirmed by changing the name of the variable to a number, and then it passes the configuration check, but unfortunately that name-number is then set to the port, and the variable is not expanded.

Does anyone have a better handle than me on what is going on here? Has anyone else been able to successfully set a port from an event field? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

ps. logstash version 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You use [fieldName] in the configs (conditionals, etc).  You would use %{fieldName} in the value of the parameter, so try this:

```
port => "%{the_port}"
```

Comment: This still throws the same error. `# This setting must be a number # Expected number, got "%{syslog_port}" (type %{syslog_port})
      port => "%{syslog_port}"`